# Find a multiple in Java

Tags: java

How would i go about finding the multiples of 3 and 5??

I'm a newb so nothing too complicated please. I know the basics however.

Would it be better creating a method, but that would take too long

I.E

if x == 3,5,6 etc.

Comment: You could make 2 sets, one set for multiples of each, then combine the sets. Otherwise I would suggest going with duffymo's answer.

Comment: Finding the multiple where? Do you already have an existing set of data, or do you just need to generate them from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (num % 5 == 0 || num % 3 == 0) // you have a multiple.
```

This will just tell you if `num` is a multiple of 3 or 5... I think you can probably figure out how to make it more general and fit any combination of numbers. Or just look at duffymo's answer.

Comment: How does that work exactly like how does the % operator work? assuming that % is an operator.

Comment: @JoeSmith `%` is the modulo operator. It finds the remainder of division of one number by another. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [modulus](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/15.html) operator for Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
package math;

/**
 * MathUtils description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link
 * @since 2/21/13 6:59 PM
 */
public class MathUtils {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] values = {
            10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
            20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
            30
        };
        int n = 3;
        int p = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(String.format("value %d multiple of %d and %d? %s", values[i], n, p, isEvenMultiple(values[i], n, p)));
        }
    }

    public static boolean isEvenMultiple(int m, int n, int p) {
        return ((m%n == 0) && (m%p == 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: or odd multiple. misnomer.

Comment: If it isn't too much trouble, you wouldn't mind explaining how it works??

Comment: Well just from the for loop please, theres alot of stuff in that, that i don't quite understand, at least not yet.

Answer (score 0):

This program only prints the nonnegative multiples, also it only prints the ones that can be represented in 32 bit 2s complement.  But of those, it should print them all, in order, and without duplication.

```
int m3 = 0 ;
int m5 = 0 ;
while( m3 >= 0 || m5 >= 0 ) {
    if( m5 < 0 || m3 < m5 ) {
        System.out.println(m3) ;
        m3 += 3 ; }
    else if( m3 < 0 || m5 < m3 ) {
        System.out.println(m5) ;
        m5 += 5 ; }
    else {
        System.out.println(m3) ;
        m3 += 3 ; m5 += 5 ; }  }
```